# Creating a .NET Web Application with Dynamic/Virtual pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

We have a certain requirement to create a Web Application that is very dynamic and generic in nature with a lot of functionality very heavily config based.

I am thinking of an architecture whereby we expose our web based features using a single dynamic page. What features this page renders and the individual settings of that feature will be configurable and driven by a master XML file/Database.

This XML file / Database will have all the configuration relating to how the page needs to render based on the URL in the browser.

Therefore I am thinking that we will have a list of URL's that will all need to redirect to this particular page. In this page I am thinking that we would check the current URL and then pick up the corresponding settings for that URL from the XML file / DB if found otherwise display nothing or a standard message.

I have two questions first of all I would like to find out if there is a way to setup a web application so that all possible URL's resolve to a certain page.

Secondly, I would like to know what could be the problems with the approach I am proposing. Is it feasible? Pros and Cons e.t.c. Just some general thoughts and discussion on that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and this probably belongs in [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In general, you are writing a Content Management System (CMS) or a light version of one. These systems store configuration info (typically in a database) and use it to render customizable pages. I would consider if you should just use one out of the box (that would depend on how configurable the users really want the system to be).

Answering your specific questions:

"if there is a way to setup a web application so that all possible URL's resolve to a certain page."  - yes, you can set blanket forwarding/rerouting/redirection rules. The specifics would depend on what you are using to host the application. This is for IIS (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969(v=ws.10).aspx). The url's would all need to be on the *domain* the box is sitting behind though.

As far as pros and cons go, this is what comes to my mind, cons:

1. A lot of boiler plate code others have already written. If the users wants something very customizable, you may want to consider using some sort of CMS and then coding some of its components. That way the users could even design/publish their own pages. This approach will save you from writing and maintaining a lot of custom code (dot net nuke is an example of a .net based CMS) to handle the configuration.
2. increased testing scope. If users are asking for X and you are building X that should also support being configured to act like Y and Z, you are going to need to test for Y and Z as well. Its a gamble with an upfront investment.
3. Single point of failure for the application (if the routing page fails, everything is unreachable)
4. Developer skillset - fully rounded (full stack) developers with the necessary javascript and backend developement skillset are harder to find than specialists. If you are building a system that dynamically renders components in the UI - the javascript for it needs to be pretty clean.

Pros:

1. Coding new features which fit into your configuration framework should be a breeze.
2. Ability to introduce new features/components during runtime - if all you need for a new component is config and a url pointing to it, you can add it to your application in runtime with a db/config insert.
3. Fitting your exact user's customization needs. This is a 'pro' of every custom approach (vs. and off-the-shelf product), since you are building the application - you can make it fit the exact business process or user experience you are working toward without any of the built-in limitations of a CMS.